# Using interpolation for calling compass sprite mixins

Tags: sass, compass-sass, css-sprites, mixins

the problem that i have with this mixing is that i can't interpolation for calling different sprite mixins that compass provides.

I want to be able to have this in one place, create the sprites in different scss and them just include this shared mixing and use it.

So far seems that Sass doesn't allow me to do that. Maybe i just have a crazy and bad way of doing things ( i'm no designer really and i learn about sass a few months ago ).

Thanks for your time.

```scss
@mixin icon-button($width, $height, $icon-bg-color, $icon, $sprite-name){
  .icon-base{
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
    background-color: $icon-bg-color;
    .icon{
      $icon-height: #{$sprite-name}-sprite-height(#{$icon});
      $icon-width: #{$sprite-name}-sprite-width(#{$icon});
      @include #{$sprite-name}-sprite(#{$icon});
      width: $icon-width;
      height: $icon-height;
      position: relative;
      left: ($width - $icon-width)/2;
      top: ($height - $icon-height)/2; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#{something}` is a ruby-way of interpolation. `Compass` framework uses ruby compiler to make css from scss/sass. Interpolation is just the way to insert some value (of a variable) into a string, like this: `puts "I want to say #{smth}"` will print `"I want to say something"` into `irb` console if you previously defined the `smth = "something"` variable. You also may notice the difference between ' and ". So, sometimes you would like to use standalone functions in compass like this:

```
headings(all) {
    color: $color;
}
```

to compile it into css:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

Instead, it throws an error. So, to do this you need to interpolate the call of the function:

```
#{headings(all)} {
    color: $color;
}
```

And it runs. But if you try to make interpolation with variables:

```
$color: #abc;
$color2: "#abc";

@mixin some($color) {
    color: #{$color};
}
```

will also throw an error because in this case interpolation outputs a string "#abc".
Try to avoid using ruby syntax in compass if it is possible for cleaner style.
Note: I would appreciate if someone can explain with better compilation details because i'm not a rubyist, i'm pythonist.

## **Update**

Check this code:

```
@mixin setFonting($from, $to, $size) {
    $curr: $from;
    $to: $to + 3;

    @while $curr != $to {
        h#{$curr} {
            font-size: $size;
        }
        $curr: $curr + 1;
        $size: $size + 2;
    }
}
@include setFonting(1, 3, 20px);
```

It compiles to :

```
h1 {font-size: 20px;} h2 {font-size: 22px;} h3 {font-size: 24px;} h4 {font-size: 26px;} h5 {font-size: 28px;}
```

So as you see, `#{}` interpolation in compass works **outside** curly brackets used to define statements for selector.